# Presentation OpenXml package not able to find source of font color

Tags: openxml, presentationml

I am reading openxml package file and at one place I am not able to figure out the source of text color

If you look into the below xml there are run elements    which contains Aug and 2019 and its color is shown as in below screenshot. I have tried to refer slideMaster1.xml and theme1.xml as per relationship but didn't get any success. Can you please help me to identify from where PPT is getting its formatting.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
  <p:cSld>
    <p:spTree>
      <p:nvGrpSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/>
        <p:cNvGrpSpPr/>
        <p:nvPr/>
      </p:nvGrpSpPr>
      <p:grpSpPr>
        <a:xfrm>
          <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
          <a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/>
          <a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
          <a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/>
        </a:xfrm>
      </p:grpSpPr>
      <p:sp>
        <p:nvSpPr>
          <p:cNvPr id="7" name="Title 1"/>
          <p:cNvSpPr>
            <a:spLocks noGrp="1"/>
          </p:cNvSpPr>
          <p:nvPr>
            <p:ph type="ctrTitle"/>
          </p:nvPr>
        </p:nvSpPr>
        <p:spPr>
          <a:xfrm>
            <a:off x="419535" y="1935956"/>
            <a:ext cx="6743266" cy="1271588"/>
          </a:xfrm>
        </p:spPr>
        <p:txBody>
          <a:bodyPr/>
          <a:lstStyle/>
          <a:p>
            <a:r>
              <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="3600" dirty="0"/>
              <a:t>PPTX to HTML</a:t>
            </a:r>
            <a:br>
              <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="3600" dirty="0"/>
            </a:br>
            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" i="1" dirty="0">
              <a:solidFill>
                <a:srgbClr val="0070C0"/>
              </a:solidFill>
            </a:endParaRPr>
          </a:p>
        </p:txBody>
      </p:sp>
      <p:sp>
        <p:nvSpPr>
          <p:cNvPr id="4" name="Subtitle 2">
            <a:extLst>
              <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{4C91A161-6A53-4B2D-8EAA-F349574D0CD9}"/>
              </a:ext>
            </a:extLst>
          </p:cNvPr>
          <p:cNvSpPr>
            <a:spLocks noGrp="1"/>
          </p:cNvSpPr>
          <p:nvPr>
            <p:ph type="subTitle" idx="1"/>
          </p:nvPr>
        </p:nvSpPr>
        <p:spPr>
          <a:xfrm>
            <a:off x="419535" y="3867150"/>
            <a:ext cx="2476066" cy="533400"/>
          </a:xfrm>
        </p:spPr>
        <p:txBody>
          <a:bodyPr/>
          <a:lstStyle/>
          <a:p>
            <a:r>
              <a:rPr lang="en-US"/>
              <a:t>Aug </a:t>
            </a:r>
            <a:r>
              <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
              <a:t>2019</a:t>
            </a:r>
          </a:p>
        </p:txBody>
      </p:sp>
    </p:spTree>
    <p:extLst>
      <p:ext uri="{BB962C8B-B14F-4D97-AF65-F5344CB8AC3E}">
        <p14:creationId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="3413077856"/>
      </p:ext>
    </p:extLst>
  </p:cSld>
  <p:clrMapOvr>
    <a:masterClrMapping/>
  </p:clrMapOvr>
</p:sld>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct reference is slide.xml -> slideLayout.xml -> slideMaster.xml i.e. if you don't find it in slide.xml check in slideLayout.xml and if you still don't find it there, check in slideMaster.xml. In your example `<p:ph type="subTitle" idx="1"/>` the ph means it's a `placeholder` so probably the styling will be found in slideLayout. When checking in the other files, look for `<sp>` node with same `type` and `idx` or just `type` where `idx` is not specified.

Example

SP node in slide.xml

```
<p:sp>
            <p:nvSpPr>
                <p:cNvPr id="4" name="Title 3"/>
                <p:cNvSpPr>
                    <a:spLocks noGrp="1"/>
                </p:cNvSpPr>
                <p:nvPr>
                    <p:ph type="title"/>
                </p:nvPr>
            </p:nvSpPr>
            <p:spPr/>
            <p:txBody>
                <a:bodyPr/>
                <a:lstStyle/>
                <a:p>
                    <a:r>
                        <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
                        <a:t>Agenda</a:t>
                    </a:r>
                    <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
                </a:p>
            </p:txBody>
        </p:sp>
```

SP node in slideLayout.xml

```
<p:sp>
    <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="5" name="Title 1"/>
        <p:cNvSpPr><a:spLocks noGrp="1"/></p:cNvSpPr>
        <p:nvPr><p:ph type="title" hasCustomPrompt="1"/></p:nvPr>
    </p:nvSpPr>
    <p:spPr>
        <a:xfrm>
            <a:off x="457200" y="51470"/>
            <a:ext cx="8229600" cy="637580"/>
        </a:xfrm>
        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
            <a:avLst/>
        </a:prstGeom>
    </p:spPr>
    <p:txBody>
        <a:bodyPr>
            <a:scene3d>
                <a:camera prst="orthographicFront"/>
                <a:lightRig rig="flat" dir="t">
                    <a:rot lat="0" lon="0" rev="18900000"/>
                </a:lightRig>
            </a:scene3d>
            <a:sp3d extrusionH="31750" contourW="6350" prstMaterial="powder">
                <a:bevelT w="19050" h="19050" prst="angle"/>
                <a:contourClr>
                    <a:schemeClr val="accent3">
                        <a:tint val="100000"/>
                        <a:shade val="100000"/>
                        <a:satMod val="100000"/>
                        <a:hueMod val="100000"/>
                    </a:schemeClr>
                </a:contourClr>
            </a:sp3d>
        </a:bodyPr>
        <a:lstStyle>
            <a:lvl1pPr algn="l">
                <a:defRPr sz="3000" b="1" i="0" cap="none" spc="0">
                    <a:ln/>
                    <a:solidFill>
                        <a:srgbClr val="000090"/>
                    </a:solidFill>
                    <a:effectLst/>
                    <a:latin typeface="Timeless-Bold"/>
                    <a:cs typeface="Timeless-Bold"/>
                </a:defRPr>
            </a:lvl1pPr>
        </a:lstStyle>
        <a:p>
            <a:r>
                <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>
                <a:t>Click to edit title in one line</a:t>
            </a:r>
            <a:endParaRPr lang="en-SG" dirty="0"/>
        </a:p>
    </p:txBody>
</p:sp>
```

In the example above you can then get the styling for the text 'Agenda' in slide.xml from `<p:sp>` -> `<p:txBody>` -> `<a:lstStyle>` -> `<a:lvl1pPr>` -> `<a:defRPr>` in slideLayout.xml